# cannot find symbol when I tried build project (maven+lombok)

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, intellij-idea, lombok

I use `lombok` in my spring mvc project. And I have some problems with `maven`. When I tried run `clean/install` in maven I have errors

```
[ERROR] \gitProjects\src\main\java\com\springapp\mvc\SuccessController.java:[62,24] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \gitProjects\src\main\java\com\springapp\mvc\SuccessController.java:[63,24] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \gitProjects\src\main\java\com\springapp\mvc\SuccessController.java:[64,24] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \gitProjects\src\main\java\com\springapp\mvc\SuccessController.java:[65,24] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \gitProjects\src\main\java\com\springapp\mvc\SuccessController.java:[66,24] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \gitProjects\demirbank\src\main\java\com\springapp\mvc\SuccessController.java:[67,24] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \gitProjects\src\main\java\com\springapp\mvc\SuccessController.java:[68,24] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \gitProjects\src\main\java\com\springapp\mvc\SuccessController.java:[69,24] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \gitProjects\src\main\java\com\springapp\mvc\SuccessController.java:[70,24] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \gitProjects\src\main\java\com\springapp\mvc\SuccessController.java:[71,24] error: cannot find symbol
```

And if I run server without `clean/install` and press debug or run button I have error to `cannot find symbol`

I eneble `Settings -> Compiler -> Annotation Processors` but not help.

But if I make `build/rebuild` and after it press `debug` button my project build fine.

How do I configure Intellij IDE to everything was going well over Maven?

Comment: Can you show the code to this `SuccessController` please?

Comment: maven build should work, right? For idea: use the lombok plugin.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using @Get and @Set in pojo/dto/bean class then in eclipse check whether it's generating the getters and setters on behalf of you using outline view.In controller if you are using @sl4j,or @log4j of lombok then check whether you are getting that object or not.